# Preloading audio on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, audio, preload

I've got some JS setup to play a sound on click. My problem is that on mobile devices the sound loads when clicked instead of playing after preload. I've attempted to use html5preloader.js and jQuery AJAX calls to preload the sound but mobile devices don't seem to respect the functions. Is it possible to preload sounds via javascript? Here's a site that has this functionality working: http://huracan.lamborghini.com/#!/en/listen

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/ding.mp3');

    audioElement.load()

    $.get();

    $('.animation, .navigation ul li, h4').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
    });
var myLoader;
    myLoader = new html5Preloader();
    myLoader.loadFiles('audio/ding.mp3','audio/ding.ogg');
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery or even with pure JavaScript you can preload audio without any plugins. I'm drafting here a simple illustration how that can be done with jQuery:

```
$("<audio>")
    .error(function () { /* ... */ })
    .on("canplaythrough", function () {
        $(this).prependTo($("body"));
        this.play();
    })
   .attr("src", "/path/to/the/sound.mp3")
   .attr("type", "audio/mpeg");
```

You may want to extend the code above to contain a set of `<source ...>` elements to support more than one filetype, add error handling etc...

What happens in the snippet:

- a new `<audio>` element is dynamically created,
- 2 event listeners are attached (one is triggered on "error" and the other on "canplaythrough" - which means that the browsers has preloaded enough data to be relatively safe that it will be able to play the whole audio without interruptions - you can also use "loadeddata" which fires when all data are preloaded),
- and the `<audio>` element is set two attributes which are the path to the sound and the type of the audio. The browser starts download the audio as soon as the attributes are set.

Note: when I was using a similar technique to preload images (using `$("<img>").load()`) this caused some memory leaks issues in older browsers. There are workarounds for that but that is out scope of this answer I think.

Comment: I introduced my problem as a mobile issue but I failed to mention that when I asked "Is it possible to preload sounds via javascript?" My mistake for being unclear. Thanks for your insight though.

Comment: Fair play, @Noah. On mobile you're right that most implementations will be hesitant to preload anything without user interactions (it might be even a part of the official specifications) to save the bandwidth. If you have found a way to preload the sound you may find the following method useful. I read about the 'audio sprites' by A. Gloege at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/ (towards the bottom of the article). Here's his jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/rQv5h/light/

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer should be helpful to some, and this was the method I was using before I realized that it wouldn't work for mobile. Apparently you can't preload media on mobile devices, there has to be a user interaction to load media. The solution was simpler than I expected:

```
$("#audio").attr('src', 'audio/ding.mp3').on("playing",function(){
    loop();  //function to run simultaneously with sound
});

$(".animation, .navigation ul li, h4").on("click tap",function (){
    document.getElementById("audio").play(); //click to trigger sound
});
```

Basically I'm just chaining the function I want to run with the audio so that it only runs after it's loaded. Hopefully this helps anyone having the same issue. It's not as convenient as preloading on page load, but I was at least able to have my other function wait for the sound to load before firing.